# How can I assert two possible values for a key in an array using Phpunit?

Tags: php, phpunit

```
$array = [a => '1',
 b => '2']
```

For example, I want to check if a was either 1 or 3. I thought using this would work.

```
$this->assertThat(
    $this->assertContains('1',$array),
    $this->logicalOr(
        $this->assertContains('3',$array)
));
```

Comment: I thought assert accepted a boolean. If so Or those bitches together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass your assertions as arguments into `logicalOr`

```
$this->assertThat($array, $this->logicalOr(
    $this->assertContains('3',$array),
    $this->assertContains('1',$array)
));
```

Comment: I would get "Failed asserting that an array contains '1'" if '3' was in the array and vice-versa

Comment: @iii what happens if you remove the $array argument from assertThat?

Comment: This error: "Failed asserting that '1' contains '3' "